# Calendar.py errors with importing datetime in program

Tags: python, datetime

Within my program I am trying to find the difference between two hours (in the format HH:MM:SS) in hours and to do this I assume I have to use the datetime module from Python. However when I run my program and it gets to the line where it is meant to calculate the difference between these times;

```
FMT = '%H:%M:%S'
TimeDifference = datetime.strptime(TimeEnd, FMT) - datetime.strptime(TimeStart, FMT)
```

I got the following error:

```
File "C:/Users/Matt/Dropbox/Computing up to date/Code\calendar.py", line 99
intyear +=1
          ^
TabError: inconsistent use of tabs and spaces in indentation
```

So I googled this error and found that the spaces and tabs within the program were conflicting (I am using Python 3.3.5) so I simply replaced the tabs within the program with spaces, however when I finished doing this I got another error:

```
File "C:\Users\Matt\Dropbox\Computing up to date\Code\calendar.py", line 188, in clsMainFrame
tk.Frame.__init__(master)
NameError: name 'master' is not defined
```

I don't want to mess around with it too much because I'm new to Python and therefore not fully aware of what I'm doing with the datetime module. Any help? I can edit this to show the entire calendar.py script, but I think most of you will already have it. Thank you for any help in advance.

Comment: You approach to compute time difference is rather correct (however `TimeDiference` will be a tuple `(0, minutes)` and not difference in hours). Reason for your error is elsewhere (near line 188 as the error message says). Apart from that please check https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0008/#naming-conventions , because you variable names are confusing.